# Is there a way to avoid the Uno Platform splash screen appearing in the Wasm app version?

Tags: uno-platform

When I run the Wasm app head the Uno Platform splash screen appears (with its white background) initially before the app UI appears.  Occasionally, the splash screen image (splashscreen.scale-200.png) and its specified background color (via AppManifest.js) appear very, very briefly in between the Uno platform splash and the app UI.  Is there a way to get the first thing that appears in the browser to be the app splash screen?

Answer (score 2):

There's already a GitHub issue with this and it's being worked.

Here's the link: https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap/issues/131

I suggest you subscribe to it so you can get notified when the fix is merged.

Hope this helps.-